# Cannot import javax.persistence.MapsId

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, maven-3

I use Spring Data JPA and I would like to use the `@MapsId` annotation in the code of one of my entities

Although I put `import javax.persistence.*;` in my entity

I have the following compilation error :

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method name()
[ERROR]   location: @interface javax.persistence.MapsId
```

My **pom.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    ...

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1210</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are missing the most important part of code: your `@MapsId` usage

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@MapsId(name = "something")`, but `name` doesn't exist on `@MapsId`.

Use `value` instead: `@MapsId(value = "something")`, or simply `@MapsId("something")`